# How can I save my mini-buffer history in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, history, buffer

I'd like to save, for instance, my find-file and Meta-X history in Emacs' mini-buffer so I can recall commands later in a different session.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As Trey Jackson said, you want to put this:

```
(savehist-mode)
```

in your Emacs start up file, then restart Emacs. (Calling it interactively will stomp on your current mini-buffer history, so you may not want to do that.)

It's also worth pointing out that you can persist other variables across sessions by adding them to `savehist-additional-variables`, like so:

```
(setq savehist-additional-variables '(kill-ring search-ring regexp-search-ring))
```

You may also want to customize `savehist-file`, to pick the location where Emacs saves all this stuff:

```
(setq savehist-file "~/.emacs.d/tmp/savehist")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on clobbering and the ability to add other history buffers. This looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: "... then restart Emacs. (Calling it interactively will stomp on your current mini-buffer history, so you may not want to do that.)"  Won't restarting Emacs, when you don't have `savehist-mode` enabled, also clobber your history?  Seems the interactive call is less destructive to Emacs state, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `(savehist-mode 1)` gives `Symbol’s value as variable is void: pell-buffer` error how can I fix it?

Comment: @alper that's gotta be something related to `pell-buffer` in your local config; without seeing it, i don't think folks will be able to offer much advice...

Answer (score 19):

```
M-x savehist-mode
```

or

```
(savehist-mode 1)
```

(available in Emacs as of 22.1)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Emacs version older than 22, you can use this instead:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/savehist-20%2b.el